# Single column dataframe containing 1D lists using a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to create a new single column pandas dataframe using a 2D numpy array. Apparently, each row should contain 1D lists. Following is a simplified reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones((4,3)) # could be any 2D array
```

What I want is,

```
       lists
0  [1, 1, 1]
1  [1, 1, 1]
2  [1, 1, 1]
3  [1, 1, 1]
```

Now, `df  = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['lists'])` gives the error,

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 3), indices imply (4, 1)
```

And `df = pd.DataFrame(list(arr), columns=['lists'])` gives the error,

```
ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

Finally, `df = pd.DataFrame(arr.flatten(), columns=['lists'])` gives a wrong dataframe with all cells having a scalar `1`.

How do I get what I want?

Comment: This was a more interesting problem than I expected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From each row of the 2d array (i.e. a 1d array), construct a singleton tuple that contains that row, and build the DataFrame from *that*. We can elegantly do this using a generator expression:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(((x,) for x in arr), columns=['lists'])
>>> df
             lists
0  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
3  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

The constructor iterates over the tuple, rather than the underlying array, in order to determine the column values in a given row. There is one such value - the 1d array - so that gets stored for that row in the single available column.

The cell values are indeed Numpy arrays:

```
>>> df['lists'][0]
array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {"lists": list(arr)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['lists'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
             lists
0  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
3  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: `[val for val in arr]` is more neatly written as `list(arr)`.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is more elegant actually :)

Comment: Absolutely. Learned something new today as well .. .:)

Answer (score 3):

Get all rows of the array, create dataframe with them. Transpose then add column name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# ones array
arr = np.ones((4,3), dtype=int)

# get all rows of the array transpose and add column name
df  = pd.DataFrame([list(arr)]).T
df.columns = ['lists']
df
```

Comment: If OP wants ints in the output, it would be better to start with a `dtype=int` for the `np.ones`, rather than converting at this step. Nice idea, though. Took me a little while to figure out what's going on :) this basically adds the wrapping at a different step in the process, but is functionally the same.

Comment: (After changing that, the same `list(arr)` advice I gave to @Anshul applies, too.)